# How to use call symput on a specific observation in SAS

Tags: sas, sas-macro, do-loops

I'm trying to convert a SAS dataset column to a list of macro variables but am unsure of how indexing works in this language.

```
    DATA _Null_;
       do I = 1 to &num_or;
       set CondensedOverrides4 nobs = num_or;
       call symputx("Item" !! left(put(I,8.))
       ,"Rule", "G");
    end;
    run;
```

Right now this code creates a list of macro variables Item1,Item2,..ItemN etc. and assigns the entire column called "Rule" to each new variable. My goal is to put the first observation of "Rule" in Item1, the second observation in that column in Item2, etc.

I'm pretty new to SAS and understand you can't brute force logic in the same way as other languages but if there's a way to do this I would appreciate the guidance.

Comment: Why are you setting all of the macro variables to same text literal value?

Comment: Where did you create the macro variable NUM_OR?  What is its purpose?

Comment: Is this related to your other question, by any chance?  Are you just doing this to then get the values copied back into another dataset?  You're asking a bunch of XY problem questions; better would be to ask one question showing what you're trying to do, as there are much better ways to do this.

Comment: @Joe num_OR is the length of the list I am trying to copy. Yeah sorry I'm not particularly experienced asking questions on SO, will think farther ahead next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much easier to create a series of macro variables using `PROC SQL`'s `INTO` clause.  You can save the number of items into a macro variable.

```
proc sql noprint;
  select rule into :Item1- 
  from CondensedOverrides4
  ;
%let num_or=&sqlobs;
quit;
```

If you want to use a data step there is no need for a `DO` loop. The data step iterates over the inputs automatically.  Put the code to save the number of observations into a macro variable BEFORE the set statement in case the input dataset is empty.

```
data _null_;
  if eof then call symputx('num_or',_n_-1);
  set CondensedOverrides4 end=eof ;
  call symputx(cats('Item',_n_),rule,'g');
run;
```

Comment: Thanks that works perfect! The only problem is it broke something else in my code in the process--actually I believe it was you that helped me with this yesterday so maybe you can offer guidance as to what went wrong. I have a macro loop that takes these variables and puts them in an array which no longer works.  %macro toMacroLoop(array);
%do j = 1 %to &num_or;
  &array[&j.] = &&Item&j;
%end;
run;
%mend;

Comment: If it helps I tried manually assigning &Item1 to a dataset and it gave me the results of column R1 from that dataset rather than the string "R1" so it seems it's copying the symbolic reference rather than a literal string--by the way both the data step and proc sql routines break my (your) code

Comment: NEVERMIND I figured it out--had to put quotes around &&Item&j; to make it work, still trying to figure out why..

Comment: Values in quotes are literals. So `"R1"` is uppercase R and digit 1. But `R1` is a reference to a variable named R1.  In your macro `%do` loop if you expand the macro variables' values without adding quotes around them then SAS will try to interpret the expanded values as code.

Answer (score 0):

SAS does not need loops to access each row, it does it automatically. So your code is really close. Instead of I, use the automatic variable `_n_` which can function as a row counter though it's actually a step counter.

```
DATA _Null_;
   set CondensedOverrides4;
   call symputx("Item" || put(_n_,8. -l) , Rule, "G");
run;
```

To be honest though, if you're new to SAS using macro variables to start isn't recommended, there are usually multiple ways to avoid it anyways and I only use it if there's no other choice. It's incredibly powerful, but easy to get wrong and harder to debug.

EDIT: I modified the code to remove the LEFT() function since you can use the -l option on the PUT statement to left align the results directly.

EDIT2: Removing the quotes around RULE since I suspect it's a variable you want to store the value of, not the text string 'RULE'. If you want the macro variables to resolve to a string you would add back the quotes but that seems incorrect based on your question.

Comment: Might as well introduce `cats` while we're at it perhaps? :)